# python -- trying to count the length of the words from a file with dictionaries

Tags: python

```
def myfunc(filename):
    filename=open('hello.txt','r')  
    lines=filename.readlines()
    filename.close()
lengths={}
for line in lines:
    for punc in ".,;'!:&?":
        line=line.replace(punc," ") 
    words=line.split() 
    for word in words:
        length=len(word)
        if length not in lengths:
            lengths[length]=0 
        lengths[length]+=1 
for length,counter in lengths.items():
    print(length,counter)
filename.close()
```

Comment: You want to count words including multiple word keys and values?

Comment: Sorry,i want to count the length of the words.I updated

Answer (score 2):

Use [Counter](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#counter-objects). ([<2.7 version](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576611/))

Answer (score 0):

You are counting the frequency of words in a single line.

```
for line in lines:

     for word in length.keys():             
         print(wordct,length)
```

length is dict of all distinct words plus   their frequency, not their length

```
     length.get(word,0)+1
```

so you probably want to replace the above with

```
for line in lines:
....

#keep this at this indentaiton - will have a v large dict but of all words
for word in sorted(length.keys(), key=lambda x:len(x)):
         #word, freq, length             
    print(word, length[word], len(word), "\n")
```

I would also suggest

1. Dont bring the file into memory like that, the file objects and handlers are now iterators and well optimised for reading from files.
2. drop the wordct and so on in the main lines loop.
3. rename length to something else - perhaps words or dict_words

Errr, maybe I misunderstood - are you trying to count the number of distinct words in the file, in which case use len(length.keys()) or the length of each word in the file, presumably ordered by length....

Comment: Hello,i tried it but it doesn't give the right results.If the file contains for example "hello there trying to test",i want to print :   length , count -> (2,1) , (4,1) ,(5,1) , (6,1).. Also,i don't want the use of lambda.Thanks!

Comment: Hang on, "hello there trying to test" is (5,2), (6,1), (2,1), (4,1) ie 2 instances of a 5 char, 1 of a 6 char etc etc etc.  Now I see what you are trying to do (please put your expected outout in your question) its easier. - see edit above

Answer (score 0):

The question has been more clearly defined now so replacing the above answer
The aim is to get a frequency of word lengths throughout the whole file.
I would not even bother with line by line but use something like:

```
fo = open(file)
d_freq = {}
st = 0
while 1:
    next_space_index = fo.find(" ", st+1)
    word_len = next_space_index - st 
    d_freq.get(word_len,0) += 1

print d_freq
```

I think that will work, not enough time to try it now.  HTH

Comment: Hello,it doesn't work.Any solution like i am trying?Line by line?Thanks for your time.